# how can I schedule a java to run as a task multiple times daily

Tags: windows, java, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

This is what I am running:

```
java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" com.ibm.labservices.AddDocument userid password FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg
```

I would like to run this 1x/hour using windows scheduler.

Comment: The Task Scheduler is fairly self explanatory (point and click). What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: You might want to add the Windows version to your question.

Comment: I was/am confused since my Java is located on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin" - do I need to specify that full path on the initial invocation of java?  The rest of my source is located on T drive is "T:\Development\INF-P8\Projects\HealthCheck-2016\hjip-timeout".  Does any of this require full qualification?  Thanks!

Comment: "my Java is located on" On what?

Comment: desktop windows 10, server is windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10,8.1,8,7:
Open Task Scheduler → Create Task (it's in the right pane; if not visible: Action bar → Create Task)

General Tab: Name (whatever you want); Description (unnecessary); If you want to run whether or not the user is logged in choose that option, if not the other. If you have to use Administrator to use your java application, check mark "Run with highest privileges," or change the user account to one who has permissions to run that task.

Triggers Tab → New: If you want it to run every hour after startup or login, change the slider to its respective in the option drop-down; If something else choose its similar. If you want to run it on the hour, every hour then choose "On a schedule" (if chosen choose the time in which it starts to do every hour). If at log in, choose the user or all users who login (depending on what you want). Check mark the "Repeat task every:". Select "1 hour" from the box. Select OK.  If you read any other things that you may want to do, just choose so by modifying the forum. Check "Enabled".

Actions Tab → Choose "Start a program" from the list → Type in `java` into "Program/script." Then type `-cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" com.ibm.labservices.AddDocument userid password FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg` into the "Add Arguments". Select OK

Conditions Tab → Deselect or uncheck-mark everything: If you want the computer to turn on just to do the task select that respective button. It doesn't look like you need internet so leave it unchecked (otherwise do). If you read any other things that you may want to do, just choose so by modifying the forum.

Settings: I would checkmark "Run task as soon as ... missed". Uncheckmark "If the task fails, restart every:". If you read any other things that you may want to do, just choose so by modifying the forum.

Click "OK" → Say "I am done" → Think "That was easier than I thought, pretty self-explanatory..."